# Error with Ogre and CMake

Tags: cmake, ogre

I installed Ogre3D 1.8.1 (the source package) on Ubuntu 12.04 and everything went fine (I managed to run some samples on the Ogre interface). However, I hit a problem while I was compiling an external project ([that one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/1.2.4/ogre-test-0.0.1.tgz/)) that needed the OpenCV, ArUco and Ogre librarys. When I run the CMake of the project, I receive the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package):
By not providing "FindOGRE.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OGRE", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OGRE" with any of
the following names:

OGREConfig.cmake
ogre-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "OGRE" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"OGRE_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OGRE"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I know where the FindOGRE.cmake is, it's in the /usr/local/lib/OGRE/cmake, but I don't know how to say to CMake to look for that folder and fix this problem.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use the [`-D`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-Dvar%3atypevalue) command line option along with the [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_MODULE_PATH) variable:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/OGRE/cmake
```

Comment: I tried the -D command, as you said, but I still hit the same problem. I also tried use the CMake-gui. I filled the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX with the /usr/local/lib/OGRE/cmake path, and the OGRE_DIR with the ogre installation folder. Is that right? Even so, occurs the same error.

Comment: Well, the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is where you will install your current project to if you do `make install`, so it's not really relevant here.  `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is a list of directories where CMake checks for "FindXXX.cmake" files when you use `find_package`.  Finally, setting `OGRE_DIR` (or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) to the ogre installation dir would need a file called OGREConfig.cmake or ogre-config.cmake to exist.  One of these would exist if ogre provided them (they are generated via `install(export...)`).  This is really what *should* be provided by ogre rather than FindOGRE.cmake I think.

Comment: Hi. I am using "Linux Mint 14". And the trick is find the cmake ogre files. In my system, the command line for cmake is `cmake . -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules/` .

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, an alternative solution would be to add the module path directly in the CMakeLists.txt. For example (tested on Debian 9):

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/share/OGRE/cmake/modules/;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
```

Just make sure to add the line before find_package is called.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it only works to set the following in `CMakeLists.txt` before `find_package`:

```
set(OGRE_DIR /usr/share/OGRE/build/sdk/CMake)
```

Note that the `CMake` directory is the one containing `OGREConfig.cmake`. For some reason, my CMake ignores `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Maybe, of some help for someone

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution work on manjaro:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/lib/OGRE/cmake;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
find_package(OGRE QUIET)

if (OGRE_FOUND)
    include_directories( ${ogre_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${OGRE_LIBRARIES})
    message(STATUS "OGRE: FOUND")
else()
    message(STATUS "OGRE: NOT FOUND")
endif()
```